# Message middleware in Django not displaying in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to use the message middleware in Django, but the view does not render it at all. What I have:

views.py

```
messages.success(request, 'Test message.')
return render_to_response('base.html')
```

template.html

```
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li class="{{ message.tags }}">{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

When I do this in the view:

```
for message in messages.get_messages(request):
    print message
```

it prints a message for every time I called the view since i last used this function, so it definitely saves the messages somewhere. It is just not sent to the template.

Additional info:

- Django version = (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)
- I added 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages' to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS. Note: I had no TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS even though it's supposed to be there since Django 1.2 so I just added it. I guess that it might not be working properly and that this might be the problem, but I don't know how to check if it is properly configured.
- I followed https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/ to set it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to render the template with a [`RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext) instead of just `Context` (which `render_to_response` uses by default) to make your template context processors available in the template. Check out the [`optional arguments` section of the `render_to_response` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#id2) then change:

```
return render_to_response('base.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped, but I thought that wasn't necessary if i added 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages' to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS. Or do I need both of them anyway?

Comment: Adding it to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` just means that it's been enabled. You need to use the `RequestContext` in your view to actually make all of the context processors used in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` available in your template.

Comment: Also, check out the `render` shortcut: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

Comment: @Dor I've already checked out the render shortcut and to be able to use it I have to upgrade to a newer version of Django. Now I'm in the process of getting everything to work again, then I might be able to use render.